# Is it possible to tell if an object is running in a different AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I want to know if I can tell what appdomain a object was created in. This is for a unit test but also useful general knowledge. I have the following pieces of code (this is example code for illustration).

```
public Foo Create()
{
    AppDomainSetup appDomainSetup = 
        new AppDomainSet { ApplicationBase = @"z:\SomePath" }

    AppDomain appDomain = 
                  AppDomain.CreateDomain("DomainName", null, appDomainSetup);

    return (Foo) appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("MyAssembly", "MyClass");
}
```

I then call

```
Foo myFoo = Create();
```

What I would like to be able to do is find out what AppDomain method on myFoo will be called in, to test that the Create method had actually created a new AppDomain. I realise that I can add a method on Foo like

```
public class Foo
{
    public string appDomainName 
    { 
        get { return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName; } 
    }
}
```

This would provide me the appdomain that Foo is running in. I don't think this is an elegant solution just for a unit test. It would be great if someone could help define a method like.

```
public string GetAppDomainNameWithDotNetWitchcraft(Foo myFoo)
{
    // Insert voodoo here.
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the responses and comments. The question I have asked has been answered and the comments have helped me realised where I was going wrong. What I really was trying to achieve is to test that a new AppDomain is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can do a bit of Spelunking via Remoting/Reflection, assuming your running in full trust. Note that you have to access a private property, and this assumes that the only thing it can find is remoting due to cross app domains:

```
    var a = Create();
    if (System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy(a))
    {
        var c = System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.GetObjRefForProxy(a);
        var ad = c.ChannelInfo.ChannelData[0];
        var propDomainId = ad.GetType().GetProperty("DomainID", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var DomainID = propDomainId.GetValue(ad,null);
    }
```

You can then compare that domain ID to your own to know if it's in your domain. Mind you, it's unlikely you'll enter the if statement if it *is* in your domain (trying to think of circumstances where you'd have a transparent proxy to an object in your own domain).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think of that.

Comment: I don't mind a bit of spelunking. That is useful. Although if I saw that in a unit test it does have a design smell :)

Comment: @btlog - I'm curious how fathoming whether an object is in a different AppDomain is a design smell, but writing a unit test to ensure it is isn't (if you get my meaning)?

Comment: . You are right. See my edit to the question. You have all helped me reaslise where I was going wrong.